# For loop not iterating through CSV with Python

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

Essentially what I am trying to do here is place all data from a CSV file into a dictionary in a nested format so I can just dump the json after I need it. I need the json formatted like `[{"name":"Ollie","email":"josh@apple.com","phone":"0444444444","sizes":[],"taskAmount":1,"singleCheckout":true,"billingDifferent":false,"favorite":true`

I have a for loop in place that should take all csv values and place them in the dictionary in my proper format.

I have tried looking at my loops and it checks out so I can't see why it doesn't work. Also, in the if statemnt if I go `new_data_dict[row[0]]` in place of `new_data_dict` it runs properly but doesnt come out in my desired format.

My code is here

```
profiles = []
new_data_dict = {}
with open("test.csv", 'r') as data_file:
    reader = csv.reader(data_file)
    for row in reader:
        if row[21] == 'null':
            new_data_dict = {"name":row[0],"email":row[1],"phone":row[15],"sizes":[],"taskAmount":1,"singleCheckout":True,"billingDifferent":False,"favorite":False,"card":{"number":row[5],"expiryMonth":row[7],"expiryYear":row[8],"cvv":row[6]},}
        else:
            new_data_dict = {"name":row[0],"email":row[1],"phone":row[15],"sizes":[],"taskAmount":1,"singleCheckout":True,"billingDifferent":True,"favorite":False,"card":{"number":row[5],"expiryMonth":row[7],"expiryYear":row[8],"cvv":row[6]},"delivery":{"firstName":row[20],"lastName":row[21], }}

print(new_data_dict)
```

My input file contains some sensitive information so I can't really show it but the code gives you an idea of what is in the rows.

What I am getting out is one iteration of the loop which also happens to be the last row of data in the csv, as if its starting backwards.

Comment: You are assigning all rows into the same single dictionary, rows at the bottom are overwriting rows at the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What went wrong?

When you are reading rows from the csv file and assigning them into `new_data_dict` in a `for` loop, you are repeatedly overwriting the rows that were already stored in it.

### How to fix it?

You can either put all of them into a list or another dictionary, for example:

```
all_records = []

for row in reader: 
    row_data_dict = {"name":row[0],"email":row[1],"phone":row[15],"sizes":[]...}

    all_records.append(row_data_dict)
```

Then the output would look like what you described as the desired output.

Comment: Turns out I was printing the wrong variable after applying your fix. Saviour!

Comment: This thing fixed my issue but I dont get it, why is the it being overwritten automatically? I am new to python

Comment: @TayyabFerozi the `=` sign means to assign value, no matter what the variable on the left of the `=` sign was holding, it will be overwritten (or set) with what's on the right. In the OP line 2, a new dictionary is declared, now it's empty, just `{}`, inside the `for` loop, this new dictionary is being replaced (set to) the new row on the right hand side of the `=` sign. Hope this helps, if not, I'd recommend to try the code yourself, and add a `print` statement inside the `for` loop.

Comment: @TayyabFerozi instead of "assign" or replace, it should be "append".